# Internet connection does not start automatically

Tags: 14.04, internet, modprobe

Few months ago I had a problem with my internet connection in my Ubuntu 14.04. Currently, the connection does not start until I execute this command:

```
sudo modprobe r8169
```

How can I fix this so that the connection will start automatically once the OS boots up.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following command:

```
echo "r8169" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

This command will put the module at the end of  `/etc/modules` file so that the module will be loaded on boot.

Comment: Thank you. The second option worked for me but not the first

Comment: @user1894963: I will have a look, this may be due to be a initramfs specific file issue..i will modify the answer..